# Typescript: Typing GroupBy

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I'm having some difficulty typing this correct. Basically

```js
function groupBy<T>(data: T[], key: keyof T): Partial<Record<T[keyof T], T[]>> {
  return data.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const group = item[key]
    acc[group] = acc[group] ?? [] // Type 'T[keyof T]' cannot be used to index type 'Partial<Record<keyof T, T[]>>'
    acc[group].push(item) // Object is possibly 'undefined'.

    return acc
  }, {} as Partial<Record<T[keyof T], T[]>>)
}

type Human = {
  gender: 'female' | 'male' | 'prefer not to say'
  name: string
  age: number
}

const data: Human[] = [
    { name: 'John', age: 20, gender: 'male' },
    { name: 'Jane', age: 20, gender: 'female' },
    { name: 'Jack', age: 30, gender: 'male' },
    { name: 'Jane', age: 50, gender: 'female' },
];

const groupedByGenders = groupBy(data, 'gender')
// Want `groupedByGenders` to have the type:
// Partial<Record<'female' | 'male' | 'prefer not to say', Human>>

console.log(groupedByGenders.female)
console.log(groupedByGenders.male)
console.log(groupedByGenders['prefer not to say']) 
// typescript should at least auto complete this, but at best it should know that it's undefined.
```

(Using the `Partial` utility type since I sometimes use string literal types instead of just `string` and can't be sure that all objects in the array contains at least one of the string literal type)

Comment: Your attempt gives [the wrong return type](https://tsplay.dev/mM1pkm) for `groupBy()`, since it claims that the output will have the same keys as the elements of your array, whereas it will really have keys corresponding to the *property values* of those elements.    I don't know how strongly you wish to type this, but [here](https://tsplay.dev/N9P2ow) is one approach.  If that meets your needs I will type up an answer explaining it.  If not, let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: @jcalz thank you very much for trying to help me out. I have updated the question to (hopefully) make it more clear.

Comment: All right, did you look at [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mAQ0vm) with my proposed solution?  Does it work for you or not?  If so, I will write an answer.  If not, what specifically breaks (and could you [edit] your code to show the use case this doesn't work for)?

Comment: Sorry @jcalz if I wasn't clear about that. I did have a look at them and updated my question because it does not solve my case. I want the groupBy to work with literal types and not just string.  So want `groupedByGenders` to have the type `Partial<Record<'female' | 'male' | 'prefer not to say', Human>>`

Comment: ❓❓ Using [my proposed solution](https://tsplay.dev/WYZ12w), `groupedByGenders` has the type `const groupedByGenders: { female?: Human[]; male?: Human[]; "prefer not to say"?: Human[]}` which is exactly the same as what you say you want (except that it's got arrays in it, not single values, which I assume is a typo on your part).  The types `Partial<Record<"x"|"y", Foo>>` and `{x?: Foo, y?: Foo}` are the same.  What *specifically* is the problem you have with my solution? Is this just a communication barrier or is there something really wrong with what I'm doing? Please help me out here.

Comment: Sorry about that @jcalz - I could not make it work, but the link you given me works (and looks the same). If you write it as an answer I'll mark it as solved 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggested typing for `groupBy()` looks like this:

```
type Serializable = string | number | bigint | boolean | null | undefined;
function groupBy<T extends Record<K, Serializable>, K extends keyof T>(
  data: T[], key: K
) {
    return data.reduce<{ [P in `${T[K]}`]?: T[] }>((acc, item) => {
        const group: `${T[K]}` = `${item[key]}`;
        const arr: T[] = (acc[group] = acc[group] ?? [])
        arr.push(item);
        return acc;
    }, {})
}
```

The idea is that the elements of the `data` array have a `Serializable` property at the `key` key, where `Serializable` is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all types that can be reasonably pressed into service as object keys when serialized as strings.  Object keys in JavaScript are always strings (with the exception of [`symbol` values](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/symbols.html) which I assume you don't care about), and if you index into an object with some non-string key it will be coerced to a string.

The implementation explicitly serializes to strings with [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) interpolation, and I give the output the corresponding [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types).  For strings this will be a no-op, but it will turn numbers like `123` into `"123"` and booleans like `false` into `"false"`, etc.  I assume in practice you'll be using mostly strings and maybe numbers.

Anyway, the return type is `` {[P in `${T[K]}`]?: T[]} ``, which is equivalent to `Partial<Record<T[K], T[]>>` when `T[K]` is some subtype of `string`.

Let's test it out with your `Human` example:

```
const groupedByGenders = groupBy(data, 'gender')
/* const groupedByGenders: {
    female?: Human[] | undefined;
    male?: Human[] | undefined;
    "prefer not to say"?: Human[] | undefined;
} */
```

Looks good.  The `groupedByGenders` type is an object of optional properties with keys `female`, `male`, and `"prefer not to say"` and with values of type `Human[]`.  So the compiler will be happy if you write this:

```
console.log(groupedByGenders.male?.map(h => h.name).join(", ")) // John, Jack
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhBOBLAhgG0QL2QI1dAvFAM7BIB2A5lAD5RkCuAttgjVNohYmcG9gPb88yMmwapUbemQAmEAGbcIMgNwBYAFDzpAY2CJ+oivH70wAIRAAeACpQIAD2ARZRKACUIO-vBlWA0gA0sAgo6Fi4EAB8wf72Ti4ybgDWECD88lA2UQAUMsjAyABcWQDaALrBqSAl-gCUUADemlCtUPAQwPTwovmFAHQdMvQ6EFaNUKUAClDcUAAGACSNNqX+5QC+8+UA-CWr5VAbuTnIOjrBiM6MDfhRTS1tT95kJFDGpmAlSytrm-NQQg-K4QRilar-dQaJ7PQxvZDweD7CqAqCnc6lD5mQ6EM46TEmbFQHY7SblOqPGFQBHwfpgehEAAWORBNyhVNaHS6PWp53ZbQ2wUaGwpGg2mk0oEgUAAEkwRKjmtC2hREggSgByeSgtAQDVsDWMXX62gasAdbXwOj8XjAfjEZAgDWUujIRgQEokcgUF3IVUlBjMBCacUaTQvN59Yqy+VkFGEUouiZkN0eqAagBS-EZZA1wT9aYATAAGYKq2Tq9NGvD6wVJ13uzUZkR6-P+qAlstqpHp7XVvVHQL1lON9PNnTJPPU9sAZlL727mv7taHytaydTTZbU4LJQArPPy3Ie1qdTXB5pylDw3DeFjIDJLABxbtuQj3yx5ArIYIao8IDVRQAegAKigCM70JB9n1fEolSePtdT2GMjTjQ5aGkORFDIZR+VaftkLlVCUQwitsNwl0ACJzQUVgyBtKA7QdEBKMI2MSKgTCFCUVQQygECgIlDQgKAxjGWgeQhFQfgAHduCoGSfGSNwWB0ZAGWgYBxPA-hGDARA8CtZJ6JktwZMZAp3ig5QYIreAiH6ftZiIIob1eIQIH6aSKBye8bJAF87IcgjHOQMAckZQF7kZfoRwgOp+gAK34bgcko4JKLqBoRKgLMc2CcdkiEoA)

Answer (score 1):

I changed the signature of the function and [now it seems to work as expected](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwE5xABwEIE8A8A0ogKYAeUJYAJgM6K1SoxjKIA+iYIAtgEYlUHBrn5wANgBpEAFVIUqdRAG9EAbQDWiFokIBdAFyIAhmFyIAvgD4AFNWNRjRmWr3SNJXEcIBKIwAVjVFhjcXwAJRIIOFRqfBd9aRc9KysVAChERFQSKBBUJHtHADoc6hAIEhsbYwgIaRhKHh9EAF405UysxGiwRhR0LDbtJs1PPQBuLqze-qDUZ1dh2og1NAxMPWW6tcHNxAB+A-VJ6ZNUVGLMEFoACxtGkmap7uzc-KQVl8tpZQsTeiBYIwUIRKIxOIJNyyVypHzpCzpdJQXCYEiIAASvFMw06WWQikERgA5MAnqESMThMSeBSqZxiZgcmShGA4FBEFA4AxjLhiV0wMYeCQjIxmKwusYCUZuPxBAikbMOUUnJjsWAlq11GdVILhSSAFJwW5gYnSKUixAAJgADNICTQiYgaXSfjquELLcSDaZKebpda7ShCQtnWTaeJKW7XrrPYbahozSYAwBmIMO6hOl2RqkWSTuvVen1gP3Jy0AVnTIZJ4ddefSp3SSoGGxI1DwAHEQ-QtessHg7A5jNJiRnBMT4U2EP0+2j27gAIIE4azgcqkcWidTAD0ACpEECQmFItFYvhZQJUL8zoXRUwWMhvlkLTLeJephZYWld9up30JCQxTiHAyA2LObZ4EuJA+FMf4znsEG4AAcp6K57GuQ4joWW7pHuPTThyh4gse4JnmKD7Xq8t4MPerBPmWr5yqgH5fogP5wQBQEgWBCHzihwowUiLCUKgwC1OiABicDcqoqp8NJkamBMiB8Ixl6WHBHLANJtBGFJcCauoslGEwIAkNIqmIAAjD8KgmEYYniLQ5kqUYVq2cZnKoGZFlGCmlinM24HUGhGwDtpcC0NIABExjRYJeFBbxARBEeYKnnE8kSNI+msexsyccBoHBYJQA).

The relevant part is this:

```js
function groupBy<
  K extends string | number | symbol,
  T extends { [k in K]: any }
>(data: T[], key: K): Partial<Record<T[K], T[]>> {
  return data.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const group = item[key];
    const arr: T[] = (acc[group] = acc[group] ?? []);
    arr.push(item);
    return acc;
  }, {} as Partial<Record<T[K], T[]>>);
}
```

The crucial bit that was missing was giving the `key` parameter a type, and have the type extend `string | number | symbol` (if not, it is not recognized as a possible key).
There is also a apparently extra typing of the local variable `arr`, that is there just to simplify the result inferred by the compiler (which I did not understand, frankly), and is safe in any case.

Comment: thanks! This is genius  - changing the order of the generics let's you write it so simple

Answer (score 0):

```
type KeysMatching<T extends object, V> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V ? K : never
}[keyof T];

type AllowedGroupValues = string | number

function groupBy<T extends Record<string, unknown>, K extends KeysMatching<T, AllowedGroupValues>, V extends T[K] & AllowedGroupValues>(data: T[], key: K): Partial<Record<V, T[]>> {
  return data.reduce<Partial<Record<V, T[]>>>((acc, item) => {
    const group = item[key] as V
    acc[group] ??= [];
    acc[group]?.push(item)

    return acc
  }, {})
}

type Human = {
  gender: 'female' | 'male' | 'prefer not to say'
  name: string
  age: number
  other: Record<string, string>
}

const data: Human[] = [
    { name: 'John', age: 20, gender: 'male', other: {} },
    { name: 'Jane', age: 20, gender: 'female', other: {} },
    { name: 'Jack', age: 30, gender: 'male', other: {} },
    { name: 'Jane', age: 50, gender: 'female', other: {} },
];

// Want `groupedByGenders` to have the type:
// Partial<Record<'female' | 'male' | 'prefer not to say', Human>>
const groupedByGenders = groupBy(data, 'gender')
const groupedByName = groupBy(data, 'name')
const groupedByAge = groupBy(data, 'age')
const groupedByOther = groupBy(data, 'other')
```